# What do Hobbits use for alarm clocks?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

Merry wakes the rest of the hobbits up at 4:30 to get a head start on the Black Riders when leaving Crickhollow.

> ‘What is it!’ cried Merry. ‘It is time to get up. It is half past four and very foggy. Come on! Sam is already getting breakfast ready. Even Pippin is up. I am just going to saddle the ponies, and fetch the one that is to be the baggage-carrier. Wake that sluggard Fatty! At least he must get up and see us off.’

Do Hobbits have clocks or alarm clocks, and if not how would they ensure they didn't oversleep and not leave early?

Comment: Taking turns standing watch?

Comment: @Valorum maybe. But Frodo and Sam don't join in

Comment: In that case, they probably just used the moon and stars as a guide. You can tell time pretty accurately if it's not overcast, certainly down to the nearest half-hour. Also, going to bed very early is a sure-fire way of getting up early.

Comment: My grandmother is not a hobbit, but she often tells me she never used an alarm clock the entire time she worked as a typist. She just woke up at the right time, every day, without fail. It's possible hobbits have similar abilities (except the lazy ones, who get other hobbits to wake them up)

Comment: When I have an important early appointment I sleep lightly and almost always wake up before my alarm. I think many people do this. Certainly escaping the Black Riders is an important appointment.

Comment: Given that they have to keep track of 7 (or 6) meals a day, it seems likely hobbits have much better time sense than humans do.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh I do the same thing. Except I'm a programmer. You simply go to bed at a reasonable hour and there's no problem waking up on time. Plus, no annoying alarm clocks.

Comment: @WayneWerner I'm a programmer, and while I don't need an alarm to get up for work, I wouldn't rely on myself being able to wake up at a really early hour like 430

Comment: @Po-ta-toe just go to bed at 8 or 9 ;)

Comment: I'd say Hobbits rely on hunger......

Comment: @WayneWerner My grandmother, when she was alive and getting old, would frequently complain about waking up at 3a.m. and being unable to get back to sleep.  Years later I learned that she didn't have insomnia, it was because she went to bed at *8*p.m.

Comment: You see, before alarm clocks, they had these things called "roosters"....

Comment: @Spencer I didn't realise roosters were programmable

Comment: @Po-ta-toe Roosters only have one setting; they crow when it starts getting light. Some roosters are more sensitive and set the rest off. Some roosters will crow when the clouds clear after a thunderstorm. (I think this is the first time in my life I have written "rooster". Where I come from it's a "cock".)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

They certainly have clocks.

> And of course they did none of these dreadful things, and everything was cleaned and put away safe as quick as lightning, while the hobbit was turning round and round in the middle of the kitchen trying to see what they were doing. Then they went back, and found Thorin with his feet on the fender smoking a pipe. He was blowing the most enormous smoke-rings, and wherever he told one to go, it went—up the chimney, or **behind the clock on the mantelpiece**, or under the table, or round and round the ceiling; but wherever it went it was not quick enough to escape Gandalf.
>
> <sup>*The Hobbit* - J.R.R Tolkien</sup>

---

> Bilbo took out the envelope, but just as he was about to set it **by the clock**, his hand jerked back, and the packet fell on the floor. Before he could pick it up, the wizard stooped and seized it and set it in its place. A spasm of anger passed swiftly over the hobbit’s face again. Suddenly it gave way to a look of relief and a laugh.
>
> <sup>*A Long-Expected Party- Fellowship of the Ring* - J.R.R Tolkien</sup>

There does not appear to be *specific* reference to alarm clocks...perhaps Tolkien did not consider it necessary to be *that* detailed.

Thing is...they probably bought or imported the clocks they did have from traders / travellers.

Tolkien gives us information on hobbits..in the *Concerning Hobbits* preface.

> They do not and did not understand or like machines more complicated than a forge-bellows, a water-mill, or a hand-loom, though they were skilful with tools.
>
> [snip]...but they had long and skilful fingers and could make many other useful and comely things.

Thus it seems likely that they *might* have had the *skill* to make clocks, they did not have the *knowledge or desire*.

Comment: Great find ....

Comment: It's interesting how the Shire has clocks there's no mention of them in supposedly more "civilized" places such as Gondor. Tolkien is taking the reader on a journey into a strange land, and he wants us to identify with the hobbits who are undertaking this as an actual journey. Hence, the shire is described as being full of home comforts readers would be familiar with as a contrast to the more out of the way places which are made to seem alien, even when the inhabitants are friendly.

Comment: Indeed, since LOTR is "influenced", at the very least, by WW1, it would have been the first time many young English men of that era would have seen foreign lands.

Comment: Plenty of folks would consider ALARM clocks to be uncivilized. :)  Many people find that when their routine is regular enough they wake up on their own, binge drinking and all-nighters tend to mess with that, but when things are regular it's pretty normal to just wake up at your "normal" time.

Comment: @Matt Thrower: But there's no mention of a lot of things in LOTR.  (Or indeed, in most stories.)  Like Gondor's garbage disposal & sewage treatment, for instance :-)

Comment: @jamesqf no indeed; but he draws attention to particular things in the shire. This is my point.

Comment: @Matt Thrower: Because those particular things establish a background for the Shire as a familiar place (to mid-20th century rural Britons, anyway).  Gondor isn't a familiar place to the hobbits, so we see just glimpses of what they encounter.  E.g. ordinary Gondorians might well have clocks, but Denethor is a great lord and so has servants to keep track of his appointments.

Comment: What do you think people did before alarm clocks existed, sleep in? They got up at the crack of dawn because of habit, sunlight, or perhaps a rooster. Drinking lots of water before you go to bed can also work as a "water clock". You'll wake up needing to use the restroom.

Comment: @mbomb007 there was a job called "knocker upper" back before people could afford personal timepieces - it was literally someone who walked around at the right time of the morning (going by the public time keeper) and knocked on your bedroom window to wake you up.  They typically had other nighttime jobs such as lamp lighter or night soil man, so knocker upper was a natural extension of their nighttime duties.

Comment: @jamesfq dude, read my comment carefully. You're repeating what it already says.

Comment: We don't know for sure that Gondor has no clocks, but it's remarkable that only Hobbits (and Men of Bree) have family names.

Comment: @Anton Sherwood: Or perhaps it's not so remarkable, if you think about it.  For instance Dwarves are rather Norse, and in our own history the Norse had patronymics - e.g. Leif Erikson, where Erik was Erik Thorvaldsson, &c.  Elsewhere you might be known by your birthplace, like Leonardo da Vinci.  Kings & other great lords, like Denethor, were seldom known by their family names...

Comment: @jamesqf, the same was true in England not so long ago.

Answer (score 2):

Paulie_D's answer points out that hobbits had clocks. Whoever made the clocks could surely have made an alarm clock, so there is no reason to suppose they didn't exist.

The hobbits had several things that seem a little out of place (more modern) compared to the rest of Middle-earth. Out of universe, I put that down to the fact that the hobbit society had already been described in *The Hobbit* before Tolkien fully developed the stories of the Third Age of Middle-earth (and settled on the technology that was available at that time).

I should also point out that it in past centuries, people managed to regularly get up early in the morning (for example, to milk cows) without alarm clocks.

### One way that Merry could have been sure to wake up before 4:30 AM

This is the end of September, so 4:30 would be well before dawn. But if Merry needed to be sure he would wake up by then, he could simply have asked Fredegar (Fatty) Bolger to stay up all night and wake him early. Fatty is not traveling with the others the next day, so he would be able to catch up on his sleep after his friends had left.

Comment: This seems to contradict your last paragraph: "Wake that sluggard Fatty! At least he must get up and see us off."

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon We can still hope that Fatty could have managed to stay awake if he had been asked.